# maven install became very slow after using "LATEST" and "RELEASE" version

Tags: maven, compilation

i'm using maven 2.2.1 in my daily work. recently i found my "maven install" become quite slow (about 3 times slower).

after doing many compile and debug, i found that its the lots of RELEASE and LATEST version dependencies(which were used to be specific numbers) that handicap the compile progress.

i know that "RELEASE" and "LATEST" are both deprecated functions in maven, and should not be used any more. but as adopting "RELEASE" and "LATEST" are something that i cannot change in my job. i can only try some luck with the code. and here they are:

```
public class DefaultMavenProjectBuilder extends AbstractLogEnabled
implements MavenProjectBuilder, Initializable, Contextualizable
{
private Map processedProjectCache = new HashMap();

public MavenProject buildFromRepository( Artifact artifact,...) {
    String cacheKey = createCacheKey( artifact.getGroupId(), artifact.getArtifactId(), artifact.getVersion() );   //  <=========   the "get key"
    MavenProject project = (MavenProject) processedProjectCache.get( cacheKey );
    if ( project != null )
    {
        return project;
    }
    Model model = findModelFromRepository( artifact, remoteArtifactRepositories, localRepository, allowStubModel );
    ProjectBuilderConfiguration config = new DefaultProjectBuilderConfiguration().setLocalRepository( localRepository );
    MavenProject mavenProject = buildInternal("Artifact [" + artifact + "]", model, config, remoteArtifactRepositories,
            null, false);

    return mavenProject;
}

private MavenProject buildInternal(String pomLocation,
                                   Model model,
                                   ProjectBuilderConfiguration config,
                                   List parentSearchRepositories,
                                   File projectDescriptor,
                                   boolean strict, String cacheKey)
    throws ProjectBuildingException
{
    //...
    cacheKey = createCacheKey( project.getGroupId(), project.getArtifactId(), project.getVersion() );   //  <=========   the "set key"
    processedProjectCache.put( cacheKey, project );
    //...
}
}
```

i found that the main reason is buildInternal() been invoked 10 times more than before. and what caused that is, "set key" and "get key" became different, for example:
set key: com.foo:bar:RELEASE
get key: com.foo:bar:1.0.11

my plan is pass the "get key" into buildInternal, and used directly as the "set key", but not sure this won't break other things...

are there any suggestions?

thanks in advance :)

Comment: You wrote ***i found my "maven install" become quite slow (about 3 times slower).*** But after which change has it become quite slow? The code of the maven-install plugin hasn't been changed for a longer time so it can't be the cause of the problem. The other thing is why are you using Maven 2 and not Maven3 ?

Comment: hi @hkmarbaise, thank you for your comment... the change is our scm begin to use RELEASE and LATEST version instead of specific version number, IMHO this cause the productCached(as the above code shows) failed for these dependencies. not sure this is a bug or not, but when i make the "get key" and "set key" the same, the speed become normal again... i'd like to use maven3 very much, but you know i'm not the BOSS :)

Comment: The question is why you need to use RELEASE and LATEST instead of fixed versions which is by definition bad practice and furthermore is not reproducible which contradicts the idea of a build system which should guarantee to make a build reproducible. What are the arguments against Maven 3?

Comment: okay, i'll paste my answer to your two questions next Monday, if i can meet my BOSS.

Comment: our architect told me that, we happen to need all our dependencies be the same latest version, and we won't suffer frome 1.0\2.0 version problem(as @stephenconnolly mentioned in http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/LATEST-RELEASE-dependency-version-td124018.html ). because all the dependencies begin with 1.*.*   ...in my point of view, "Maven Versions Plugin" maybe better suited for our environment, but can't persuade him to use it.

Comment: I hope it was you giving the link to my post and not the “architect”. if it was the “architect” you have my permission to tell him I say "he is a moron". `RELEASE` and `LATEST` were only designed to work for *plugins* not *dependencies*, and even there they are moronic. Seriously start looking for a job at another company if the guy does not cop on and switch to something more sensible... heck even version ranges is more sensible, though also a tad moronic.